# Android fragment push up

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a home `Fragment` and I want to use a swipe up gesture to change the home `Fragment` to a detail `Fragment`. The second `Fragment` should be preloaded and the transition should move upwards both `Fragment`s edge to edge.

I know the transition framework, but how can I preload the detail `Fragment`?

Edit: The `ViewPager` preload 3 `Fragment`s. Left/Current/Right. I need this behavior in my app, but in vertical and just 2 `Fragment`s.

Comment: Why don't you use [**this**](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/blob/master/src/VerticalViewPager.java)? I found this link in 5 seconds on Google. I am sure asking this question took longer than that...

Comment: I found this one as well, but I didn't want to use a real pager.

Comment: Why? You know those 2881 lines of code in this `VerticalViewPager` are not just for fun. What you are trying to do isn't that simple. I guess I could slap something together for you, but it will never work as well as this `VerticalViewPager`.